# After update IMac to masOS BigSur 11.3 Android emulator stop work

Tags: android-studio, qemu, macos-big-sur

Yesterday I have updated my Mac to macOS BigSur 11.3
And android emulator qemu-system-x86_64 has stopped working

At first, when launching, an error was issued

> the emulator process for avd was killed

I tried to reinstall Android studio and after that, the emulator just hangs and is not displayed
[image]

Comment: Which emulator version was causing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

the new update 30.5.6  of the android emulator has solved this problem. Hooray!!!